# PHP MultipleIterator doesnt work

Tags: php, arrays

Hello i have a problem to load multiple arrays in foreach to show data from multipleIterator.
In the arrays are the fulls data but in the iterator in foreach shows me nothing.

```
$date = array();
$time = array();
$message = array();
```

this are my arrays that are filled from mysql result and this works in this arrays all is all data.

and i made this

```
$iterator = new MultipleIterator();
$iterator->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($date));
$iterator->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($time));
$iterator->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($message));
```

and my foreach is

```
 foreach($iterator as $i)
 {
   echo $i[0];
   echo $i[1];
   echo $i[2];
}
```

but it shows me nothing its empty please help whats the mistake?

Comment: But `$date`, `$time` and `$message`  are __empty__.

Comment: @u_mulder read the descripion ITS NOT EMPTY when i foreach only the arrays $date or the other it shows me full data

Comment: there nothing wrong with this code

Comment: Here's a fiddle that works fine https://3v4l.org/nW8hC, so check that arrays are not empty. Also `var_dump($i)` to see what it is.

Comment: when i made this     foreach($date as $s) { echo $s. "<br>"; }   its shows me all dates in the array really i dont know whats the problem its make me crazy

Comment: It maybe a problem with keys. Just check what keys are in `$i`. To do this you need to change your `foreach` to `foreach($iterator as $keys => $i)` and add `var_dump($keys);`

Comment: @KarolSamborski thanks but it shows me also nothing

Comment: So maybe you should create `MultipleIterator` with flags `MultipleIterator::MIT_NEED_ANY|MultipleIterator::MIT_KEYS_NUMERIC`. Does it help?

Comment: @KarolSamborski yes i tried this but it doesnt help :( :( :(

Comment: Could you show what actually is in those three arrays?

Comment: @KarolSamborski i make a foreach with $date only it shows me 08.2018  08.2018 08.2018 and the same with time 09:30   10:30  11:30   and message also 3 messages in all arrays are data from the mysql result but in the iterator is nothing

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://3v4l.org/gP6vm). It works this way so your arrays must have some different structure. Please paste here output of `var_dump([$date, $time, $message]);`